# Angular directive over directive

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-directive

I am developing an app using Angular and ngrx. And trying to use `ng-busy` for loading indicator show. But I have to subscribe/unsubscribe manually to an state and then pass this subscription to `ng-busy` directive.

Now I want to develop another directive to accept an Observable and then inside itself, do the subscription job and adding `ng-busy` directive to the element. So, instead of this one:

```
<form [ngBusy]="[_subscription]">
</form>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<form [ngRxBusy]="[_currentUser$]">
</form>
```

and inside `ng-rx-busy`, do the subscription and add the directive `ng-busy` to the element. Now, I now how to do the subscription, but not about how to add `ng-busy` directive inside `ng-rx-busy`. Is it possible to add a directive while in another directive, at all? And if yes, how to do that?

Comment: you should use a component for this

Comment: But I want it as an attribute directive to be able to add it to any element for its loading jobs.